# How to make a complaint as a comsumer in Germany without going to court?

Tags: germany, consumer-protection

I'm not familiar with German law, but I'd like to complain about a certain international company as I was tricked by a company to pay to use a method that was shut down by the company online and many people have been complaining about this in comments. I really don't want to go into the details of how things went, as that's what I'd like to bring to the specific authorities but are there any places (official authorities) for consumers to complain about an encounter in online shopping. I've also complained to the company.

Comment: In Germany consumer protection law generally is not enforced by the government, but only through private claims. Frist the rights of the consumer, but you don't want to use this. Second there are special associations working for consumer protection (esp. the metioned Verbraucherzentrale), that have the right to sue a company for breachs of consumer protection law. Competitors and their societies have similar rights. So there is no competent authority for this, only some private institutions may be interested.

Answer (score 4):

You can complain anywhere you want. Facebook, Twitter, review sites, write your own blog, etc. It really depends on what you are trying to achieve.

The equivalent to the better business bureau are probably these guys: https://www.verbraucherzentrale.de/ I wouldn't get my hopes up that anyone would actually do something, if that's what you want.

Comment: In the U.S. there are regulatory agencies that accept complaints about consumer protection issues who may or may initiate their own investigations and/or prosecutions in a quasi-criminal manner if they receive complaints that are numerous or serious enough to merit action. I suspect that this is what the OP is asking about, but don't know enough about German consumer protection agencies to answer myself.

Comment: An example. https://www.denverpost.com/2021/03/02/colorado-consumer-complaints-airlines-frontier-robocalls/